# bind and unbind between keyframes JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

I am creating an application, as a part of it I am doing this. I have three nodes say 40, 45, 50

[image]

I have to animate to get to the position of 
[image]

To do this I have an intermediate position

[image]

I have achieved this as a part of two animations. To keep the lines joining the nodes intact, I am using `DoubleProperty.bind()` . But I want to do it as part of one animation. Here I must be able use `DoubleProperty.bind()` in middle of an animation. Does anyone have any idea out to do this?

Here is the code I wrote to achieve it.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Visual;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 *
 * @author apple
 */
public class BindIt extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Line line1 = new Line(200, 50, 100, 100);
        Line line2 = new Line(100, 100, 200, 200);

        Circle c1 = new Circle(25);
        c1.setCenterX(200);
        c1.setCenterY(50);
        line1.startXProperty().bind(c1.centerXProperty());
        line1.startYProperty().bind(c1.centerYProperty());

        Circle c2 = new Circle(25);
        c2.setCenterX(100);
        c2.setCenterY(100);
    //    line1.endXProperty().bind(c2.centerXProperty());
     //   line1.endYProperty().bind(c2.centerYProperty());

        line2.startXProperty().bind(c2.centerXProperty());
        line2.startYProperty().bind(c2.centerYProperty());

        Circle c3 = new Circle(25);
        c3.setCenterX(200);
        c3.setCenterY(200);
        line2.endXProperty().bind(c3.centerXProperty());
        line2.endYProperty().bind(c3.centerYProperty());

        Group root = new Group();
        root.getChildren().add(line1);
        root.getChildren().add(line2);

        root.getChildren().add(c1);
        root.getChildren().add(c2);
        root.getChildren().add(c3);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Bind the line!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        final Timeline timeline1 = new Timeline();
        timeline1.getKeyFrames().addAll(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(0)), 
            new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(3000), 
                new KeyValue(c2.centerYProperty(), 200), 
                new KeyValue(c2.centerXProperty(), 50), 
                new KeyValue(c3.centerYProperty(), 100), 
                new KeyValue(c3.centerXProperty(), 100)));

        timeline1.play();
        final Timeline timeline2 = new Timeline();
        timeline2.getKeyFrames().addAll(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(0)), 
            new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(3000), 
                new KeyValue(c3.centerXProperty(), 200), 
                new KeyValue(c3.centerYProperty(), 50), 
                new KeyValue(c1.centerXProperty(), 250), 
                new KeyValue(c1.centerYProperty(), 100), 
                new KeyValue(c2.centerXProperty(), 100), 
                new KeyValue(c2.centerYProperty(), 100)));

        timeline1.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                line1.endXProperty().bind(c3.centerXProperty());
                line1.endYProperty().bind(c3.centerYProperty());
                timeline2.play();

            }
        });

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Here I don't want to use two timelines but only one timeline.

Comment: Can you post some code, and some clearer requirement (i.e. under what circumstances should the lines change topology?)

Comment: Are you re-balancing a binary tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`KeyFrame` constructor that takes an event handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/KeyFrame.html#KeyFrame-javafx.util.Duration-javafx.event.EventHandler-javafx.animation.KeyValue...-) to perform an action at that key frame (in this case, establishing the additional binding):

```
    final Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
    timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(
        new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(0)),
        new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(3000),
            event -> {
                line1.endXProperty().bind(c3.centerXProperty());
                line1.endYProperty().bind(c3.centerYProperty());
            },
            new KeyValue(c2.centerYProperty(), 200), 
            new KeyValue(c2.centerXProperty(), 50), 
            new KeyValue(c3.centerYProperty(), 100), 
            new KeyValue(c3.centerXProperty(), 100)),
        new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(6000),
            new KeyValue(c3.centerXProperty(), 200), 
            new KeyValue(c3.centerYProperty(), 50), 
            new KeyValue(c1.centerXProperty(), 250), 
            new KeyValue(c1.centerYProperty(), 100), 
            new KeyValue(c2.centerXProperty(), 100), 
            new KeyValue(c2.centerYProperty(), 100)));
```

Comment: what if I won't know what lines I have to bind? I can't add these lines programmatically right? I will know which lines to bind only at runtime, I can't hard type it.

Comment: I can't really answer that without knowing what the requirements are for when you want the lines to change topology. But you can invoke any arbitrary logic you need in the event handler, so in theory, yes, you can figure that out programmatically.

Comment: I need to bind 10 or 8 lines, which I know only at the runtime. Now can I add statements to EventHandler?

Comment: Yes, of course. You can basically execute any code you want in there.